# Do we know a lower bound for the number of critical zeros of the Riemann zeta-function with irrational imaginary part?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

If I'm not mistaken, the imaginary parts of the critical zeros of the Riemann Zeta function are conjectured to be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I think we're very far from proving such a thing. Do we at least know if infinitely many of them are irrational? Do we know a lower bound for the number of such zeroes? If not, do we know at least one critical zero of $\zeta$ whose imaginary part is irrational?
Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121786/rational-roots-of-riemanns-zeta-function) and its answers. According to them, no critical zero is known to have irrational imaginary part (although they of course should be even transcendental and linearly independent over the rationals).